# Is there a way to collect statistics from cargo test?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust, so I might not be using all the terms right and so on. Therefore, please, bear this in mind when answering.

I'm joining a team with a substantial Rust code base. We use cargo to build, test, and so on. We have lots of tests, which (collectively) take a long time to run. Of course, most run fast. I'd like to identify the slow ones. Does cargo test have a feature that does this? If not, seems it would be fairly easy to look at the output of cargo test to capture the information that I'm interested in, but I don't want to re-invent that wheel if there is already a good solution out there.

Comment: Another way to address my problem would be if cargo test had a time out flag. Apparently, it doesn't have that (yet): https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9776

Answer (score 3):

On nightly compilers, you can use some unstable flags to get these statistics.

Passing the unstable `--report-time` to the test executable makes it output the time it took for each test to run:

```
$ cargo +stable test -- -Z unstable-options --report-time
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running target/debug/deps/numerals-1da2b04c985a7342

running 5 tests
test roman::test::value_checked_err_on_large ... ok <0.000s>
test roman::test::value_panic_on_large ... ok <0.000s>
test roman::test::test_big_numbers ... ok <0.002s>
test bt::test::test_many_numbers ... ok <0.009s>
test roman::test::test_many_numbers ... ok <0.023s>

test result: ok. 5 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.02s

   Doc-tests numerals

running 5 tests
test src/roman.rs - roman (line 9) ... ok <0.249s>
test src/roman.rs - roman (line 38) ... ok <0.257s>
test src/roman.rs - roman (line 55) ... ok <0.269s>
test src/roman.rs - roman (line 72) ... ok <0.303s>
test src/roman.rs - roman (line 23) ... ok <0.318s>

test result: ok. 5 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.32s
```

You can combine the unstable `--format json` and the `--report-time` flags to have the test executable output as structured JSON that contains the execution time of each test. Running `cargo test -- -Z unstable-options --report-time --format json 2> /dev/null` on the same crate gives:

```json
$ cargo test -- -Z unstable-options --report-time --format json 2> /dev/null
{ "type": "suite", "event": "started", "test_count": 5 }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "bt::test::test_many_numbers" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "roman::test::test_big_numbers" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "roman::test::test_many_numbers" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "roman::test::value_checked_err_on_large" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "roman::test::value_panic_on_large" }
{ "type": "test", "name": "roman::test::value_checked_err_on_large", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.00002701 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "roman::test::value_panic_on_large", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.000070299 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "roman::test::test_big_numbers", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.0014721 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "bt::test::test_many_numbers", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.009415822 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "roman::test::test_many_numbers", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.019445221 }
{ "type": "suite", "event": "ok", "passed": 5, "failed": 0, "allowed_fail": 0, "ignored": 0, "measured": 0, "filtered_out": 0, "exec_time": 0.01973012 }
{ "type": "suite", "event": "started", "test_count": 5 }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 23)" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 38)" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 55)" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 72)" }
{ "type": "test", "event": "started", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 9)" }
{ "type": "test", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 9)", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.25434107 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 72)", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.25587009 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 55)", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.28541328 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 38)", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.304906301 }
{ "type": "test", "name": "src/roman.rs - roman (line 23)", "event": "ok", "exec_time": 0.314071325 }
{ "type": "suite", "event": "ok", "passed": 5, "failed": 0, "allowed_fail": 0, "ignored": 0, "measured": 0, "filtered_out": 0, "exec_time": 0.314348062 }
```

Each line is a single compilation event, as structured JSON. You could parse the data to determine which tests have the longest `exec_time` fields.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! One thing that seems to not be reported is WHERE tests are coming from. E.g. the first event in your second example just says that some suite got started (and has 5 tests within the suite), but WHICH suite is it? There doesn't seem to be any identifying information. If I later want to launch just that suite, how do I specify to cargo the suite that I want? This is esp important if there are a bunch of Cargo.toml files within my source tree! Or if I want to attribute the exec_time reported in the (corresponding) end event to the suite? Am I missing something?

Comment: @allyourcode It doesn't seem like there's a way to get that data in a structured format (passing `--message-format=json` to Cargo doesn't seem to affect the relevant lines), but you could remove the `2> /dev/null` (which ignores STDERR) and instead parse the `Running unittests (target/debug/deps/numerals-b8090cf00badd992)` lines that get sent to STDERR. You can use the `--lib [target name]` flag to rerun the unit tests for a particular library, and similarly the `--bin` for binary tests, `--example` for example tests, `--bench` for bench tests, and `--doc` for the doc tests.

Comment: That used to work on the stable Cargo as well, but Rust 1.70 stable have disabled it (unfortunately!!). Is there another way to obtain test execution times & output in json format without having to use unstable Rust nowadays? Or is there a way of just using unstable Cargo (to have access to the unstable measurements) but having the program compiled with stable Rust? Maybe it would be a good idea to include options for stable Rust in your great answer...